# How to set a base member generic List<T> using derived specific List<TUser>

Tags: c#, generics, generic-list

I have a compiler error when trying to set a generic base collection class member in this derived class.

`error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<IntSegment>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<T>'`

Here's the outline of my generic collection

```
public class Path<T> : IEnumerable<T> where T : Segment
{
    private List<T> segments = new List<T>();

    public List<T> Segments
    {
        set { segments = value; }
        get { return this.segments; }
    }

    public Path()
    {
        this.Segments = new List<T>();
    }

    public Path(List<T> s)
    {
        this.Segments = s;
    }
}
```

A derived generic class of this collection is then defined for a derived class IntSegment of Segment (for which the base collection is defined)

```
public class IntersectionClosedPath<T> : Path<T>, IEnumerable<T> where T : IntSegment
{
    public IntersectionClosedPath(List<IntSegment> inEdges)
        : base()
    {
        Segments = inEdges;
    }
}
```

I can't understand why this assignment is not allowed. (I don't need to make a deep copy of the incoming List).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change `List<IntSegment> inEdges` to `List<T> inEdges` and it will work.  The problem is that `Segments` is known as a `List<T>`, `where T : IntSegment`, while `inEdges` is a `List<IntSegment>`.  (For reasons I'll not go into here unless you ask, such an assignment is not allowed.  Look up variance/covariance/contravariance if you're interested.)

Comment: Thanks this works...i'll bear the reading material in mind for later. I guess the only risk is that i have a collection which is supposed to contain the derived members but doesn't - if i accidently send in a List of the base. I'm not worried about this now, so no problem.

Comment: With the generics restrictions that exist, you won't be able to compile something that accidentally sends in a List of the base.  What you send in will always have to be a `List<T>`, and T will always have to match exactly.  E.g. this (assume `class ExtendedIntSegment : IntSegment` exists) won't even compile: `new IntersectionClosedPath<ExtendedIntSegment>(new List<IntSegment>());` Because ExtendedIntSegment and IntSegment aren't exactly the same.  If you make those two types the same, either of those, it'll compile and work just fine, with great type safety.

Answer (score 4):

A classic problem. A `List<Derived>` cannot be implicitly converted to a `List<Base>`.

You can cast the items in a `List<Derived>` and create a `List<Base>` like this:

```
listOfBase = listOfDerived.Cast<Base>().ToList();
```

Comment: I'm being a pedant, but this won't quite work - `Cast<T>()` returns an `IEnumerable<T>`, not `List<T>`

Comment: Grr! Forgot the ToList. Fixed now.

Comment: I don't quite understand this as i'm not trying to convert from base to derived but the other way round.

Comment: D'oh! I must be still sleeping.

Answer (score 3):

A `List<T>` is not equivalent to a `List<TBase>` where `T : TBase`.

Why? Because `List<T>` doesn't *inherit* from `List<TBase>`, only the generic type parameters are related.

You can instead do this in the constructor:

```
Segments = inEdges.Cast<Segment>().ToList()
```

I would also change the constructor parameter to `IEnumerable<IntSegment>`

Equally, it might be that @Tim S. has the best solution based on what you want to achieve.  Personally I believe he's probably nailed it.

Comment: Am I right in thinking that in either choice when i access the Segment List after casting i'll still have access to the IntSegment members?

Comment: @gwizardry - In `IntersectionClosedPath` yes.